# AUC based on Rehimann Sum in R

Tags: r, integral, auc

I am dealing with a dataset with dates and various response values at different time intervals as shown below

```
Id     Date         Response
1      2008-03-12   4.88
1      2009-06-06   5.39
2      2015-10-22   8.61  
2      2019-09-26   6.20
3      2006-09-28   7.40 
3      2009-07-15   7.25
3      2011-01-19   9.50
```

Dates are `X values`, Response `y values`.

I am interested in estimating the AUC for each Id. Any suggestions for accomplishing this is much appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555916/r-auc-of-multiple-samples-in-time-series) may help.

Comment: @PaulvanOppen, the proposed solution does not appear to use the dates, rather uses a column outcome which is a binary 1 or 0.